# How to get partial objects from a database with hql when having two datasources?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hql

Here is my problem.
I have to develop a REST controller that expose datas from an old database.
As this database was badly designed (by an older developper), some relevant datas are in an other database...

Here, I get a user from the first database, but this user has a birthdate stored in the second one.

In the table where we can find the user birthdate, there are also many fields that I just didn't took in consideration, that's why i am speaking about a partial object.

My hibernateConfig is like that :

```
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"com.project.persistence.config"})
public class HibernateJpaConfig {
@Autowired
Environment environment;
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataSource")
private DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("secondDataSource")
private DriverManagerDataSource secondDataSource;

@Bean
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.project.core.model"});
    final JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(this.hibernateProperties());
    return em;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondEntityManager() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(this.secondDataSource);
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.project.core.model"});
    final JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(this.hibernateProperties());
    return em;
}

@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
@Autowired
public JpaTransactionManager txManager() {
    final JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager().getNativeEntityManagerFactory());
    return txManager;
}

@Bean(name = "secondTransactionManager")
@Autowired
public JpaTransactionManager secondTxManager() {
    final JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(secondEntityManager().getNativeEntityManagerFactory());
    return txManager;
}

/**
 * To get the hibernate properties.
 *
 * @return The properties
 */
Properties hibernateProperties() {
    return new Properties() {
        {
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                HibernateJpaConfig.this.environment.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", HibernateJpaConfig.this.environment.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        }
    };
  }
}
```

My DAO is like this:

```
import com.projet.core.model.Birthdate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;


@Transactional("secondTransactionManager")
@Repository
public class BirthdateDao extends Dao<Birthdate>{
    private static final String QUERY =
        "SELECT new Birthdate(b.idBirthdate, b.birthdate, b.registrationNumber) FROM " + "Birthdate as b";
    public BirthdateDao() {
        this.persistentClass = Birthdate.class;
    }

    /**
     * @return list of birthdates
     */
    public List<Birthdate> getAllBirthdates() {
        return this.entityManager.createQuery(QUERY).getResultList();
    }
}
```

My entity looks like that:

```
package com.projet.core.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "donneesPersonne")
public class Birthdate extends AEntity{
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT", name = "matricule")
    private final String registrationNumber;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT", name = "dateNaissance")
    private final String birthdate;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idDonneePersonne")
    private final Long idBirthdate;

    public Birthdate(final Long idBirthdate, final String birthdate, final String registrationNumber) {
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
        this.idBirthdate = idBirthdate;
    }

    public String getRegistrationNumber() {
        return this.registrationNumber;
    }

    public String getBirthdate() {
        return this.birthdate;
    }
}
```

But getAllBirthdates returns an empty list (more than 300 rows in database).
Can you help me to find where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would design an ETL process to move over and decommission the old DB. 300 rows is nothing, so it should be relatively easy. After you consolidate your data into a single DB, you can avoid this whole headache.

Comment: We thought about it, but our second database is encrypted, so we don't have any mean to link those datas with the ones in the first database, except decryting it in our code.

Comment: So write a small job (leveraging the same code) to decrypt from second DB and insert to the primary DB.